# Where do I put code that links app to Twitch OAuth and channel chat

Tags: android, oauth, twitch

I'm currently using Android Studio 3.0.1 to build a very small android app that will be used to send specific chat commands to the users twitch channel chat. It's been quite a while since I've dabbled and as such I'm getting lost with where to put certain things

Essentially what I need the app to do is two fold. Firstly I need to present the user with the Twitch authentication page on first open so that they can authorise the app to use their twitch account/channel. Then I have a single screen with buttons on it. Each button calls a certain string, and what I need to do is pass that string into the users channel chat

I've got virtually all the code required to connect to the twitch API and generate the OAuth request, as well as code connecting to the channel and code to push commands from the buttons out to another endpoint. What I'm struggling with is the following:

Where do I put any of this code? Where am I putting the twitch OAuth request code etc? Do I create a separate Java class for it?

Once I've got the code in and working where is the data being stored and how do I then call it elsewhere? I guess this might get answered once I know where I'm actually putting the main code

Obviously the app will be used by multiple users so I assume I'll be creating variables for usernames, OAuth tokens etc and then will call them from other areas. I'm just unaware of how to get this done in the current Studio version and while I can find lots of references to what code to use, and plenty of examples of how to make code work I can't seem to find any info on where to actually put any code

Comment: I'm thinking of maybe adding a front page to the app with a connect to twitch button. User clicks button and if they haven't authenticated they get that page, if they have then it'll connect them based on stored credentials. So would I add the auth code to the button directly or make a new Java class and call that from the button?

Comment: I've abandoned android studio for now. no matter what I tried I can't get things working. switching over to another method of working using html/js/css and I've got so much further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've abandoned android studio for now. no matter what I tried I can't get things working. switching over to another method of working using html/js/css and I've got so much further